# Error while inserting values of multiple lists into columns of database (SQL Server + Python)

Tags: python, sql-server

I have created a Dataset containing the various attributes of tweets extracted from Tweepy, the Twitter API. I am trying to insert values from various columns of that Dataset into a database created in SQL Server, by typecasting each attribute into a list. I know this is probably THE worst way to go about this, but once I have the problem solved I'll definitely be improving this code.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=***;Database=Tweets;User Id=***;Password=***;')
cursor = connection.cursor()

    ID_list = list(dataset['ID'])
    text_list = list(dataset['Text'])
    fav_count_list = list(dataset['Favourite_Counter'])
    retweet_count_list = list(dataset['Retweet_Counter'])
    timestamp_list = list(dataset['Timestamp'])
    location_list = list(dataset['Location'])

    for i in range(1,len(ID_list),1):
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Tweet(ID,Text,Favourite_Counter,Retweet_Counter,Timestamp,Location) VALUES(%?,%?,%?,%?,%?,%?)',(tweetID_list[i],text_list[i],fav_count_list[i],retweet_count_list[i],timestamp_list[i],location_list[i]))
        connection.commit()

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Once I execute this code block, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-a61238cf4963> in <module>()
     11 
     12 for i in range(1,len(ID_list),1):
---> 13     cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Tweet(ID,Text,Favourite_Counter,Retweet_Counter,Timestamp,Location) VALUES(%?,%?,%?,%?,%?,%?)',(tweetID_list[i],text_list[i],fav_count_list[i],retweet_count_list[i],timestamp_list[i],location_list[i]))
     14     connection.commit()
     15 

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

I've been trying to solve this for a good part of 2 hours, with not much progress. Can anyone please help me and give me a good solution for solving this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are using ODBC for connecting to the database.  `Timestamp` is an ODBC reserved word (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)).

Try escaping it, using `[Timestamp]` (or change the name to something safer).

Comment: Changed it to [Time_stamp]. It still didn't work. Was the underscore a sufficient change or should I give the variable a new name entirely?

Comment: @Mominaathar . . . `Time_Stamp` is not reserved, so that is okay.  There is clearly some other error.

Comment: Will check and post here if I find the fix. Thanks for your help! :)